# How to install windows software on Android platform

Tags: windows, android-emulator

How. Can I install windows software on Android platform ?

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible. Android devices (generally) use the ARM processor, which is oriented towards mobile devices.

PCs in the past and today use x86 or x64 (amd64) processors, which are completely different and **NOT COMPATIBLE**.

The best solution I would have for you would be to use a software like Limbo PC Emulator.

The original Limbo (which I knew and used) was on Google Code, and will therefore go down with it in it's destruction.

However, it appears someone has made a fork of Limbo, at http://limboemulator.weebly.com/.

The original Google Code (for anyone who wants it), is available at https://code.google.com/archive/p/limbo-android/.

> Note: it appears, on these websites, that Windows 8.1 is running on an Android device. However, these are test devices and might be faster. Also, they used a modified version of Limbo/QEMU with more hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, Android doesn't support running Windows applications. However it's theoretically possible to [install Windows on some devices](http://www.instructables.com/id/Run-Windows-XP-on-Android-Device/) and afterwards you can indeed run Windows apps there:

[image]